# Eigen-decomposition one eigenpair by one eigenpair?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-complexity, matrix-decomposition, svd

Is it possible to conduct an Eigen-decomposition of a matrix one eigenpair by one eigenpair?

---

I am trying (hard) to find a way to reduce the time complexity of my algorithm which involves the calculation of eigendecomposition of a positive definite matrix. The full eigendecomposition is $O(n^3)$ in general. However, I may not need full eigendecomposition. I only need to stop when the $\lambda_i$, i.e. the $i$-th largest eigenvalue (and its eigenvector), is less than $\epsilon>0$.

Is there a way to do that? We might assume we know the number of eigenvalues greater or equal to $\epsilon$, if necessary, e.g. something like truncated eigendecomposition. Thanks!

---

(By the way, is MATHEMATICS the best place to ask such question?)

Comment: Sure. Power iteration with deflation is what you suggest, and can be OK. Krylov methods like Lanczos are the most popular, and what is done under the hood if you use the low rank "svds" functions in python/numpy or Matlab. LOBPCG is another option. Randomized SVD is a newer approach that is quite good. This might fit better on the scicomp stackexchange